# Saving Label Text Size, Placement, Wrapping, As Template using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I am using QGIS 3.4.

Is it possible to export & save formatted labels as a template in a file that can be opened in future projects?

Ideally, it would save my manual label placement, text size, wrapped characters/alignment to save time in future projects.  I figured out how to do this for a customized color ramp, but cannot figure out how to do it for labels.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to create a **qml** stlye file.

After you have set appropriate label style in the layer properties dialogue window:

[image]

1. Click on [Style] button and open a small context menu.
2. Select **Save Style...** which opens a new `Save Layer Style` window.
3. Make sure **Labels** option is ticked.
4. Save the style as a QML style file.

Next time when you need the style back, select **Load Style...** and open the qml file (icon will look like below):

[image]