# When moving label other labels disappear in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point, labeling

I have a set of points with labels set to lat and long generated using the
"Lat Lon Tools" plugin.

I want to move the labels using the move label tool.

[image]

[image]

When I move a label, the other labels disappear.

I have tried with a simple set of points with labels set to name and the primary key to the `"ID"` and it works fine.

Comment: More details please. What plugin? Screen shots would be helpful to better explain the problem.

Comment: I used the lat lon tools / conversions / point layer to fields

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/431649/107424

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your table doesn't have a primary key (unique id) column. Therefore, you must add one. To do that, click the "Field Calculator" button above the table [image]. Set options as in the image below:

[image]

And use `UID` as the primary key when you want to move labels.

When labels are too close or overlapping, QGIS hides some of them. To show all labels, do the following:

- In **Labels** tab in **Layer Styling (<kbd>F7</kbd>)**, open the **Rendering** tab.
- Check "*Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)*"

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kadir, that’s just the answer I needed. How do I save the layer so that the label settings are preserved, please?

Comment: Check this post please: [Saving Label Text Size, Placement, Wrapping, As Template using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324873/29431).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this and it saves the style but to add the placement locations I used move label to create I have to set the data defined x and y coordinates to the auxiliary fields manually. Is this the only way to have the labels placed the same when the saved layer is loaded?

Comment: I don't know. It's the only way I know.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the hang of it